# How do I execute non-module third-party scripts with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to use webpack and Semantic UI in an app. I need `semantic.js` to be loaded with my page and would like to put it in my "vendor" bundle. The file `semantic.js` has a dependency on JQuery, but does not export anything of its own. I just need to ensure that the code inside the file is run at some point. I have taken a look at the docs for Webpack, but I can't seem to figure out the correct approach for this.

Comment: How are you consuming `semantic.js`? Do you have a `require` set up against it?

Comment: No, I don't `require` it because it does not export anything. It just does its stuff `onDocumentReady`. My code does not interact with it in any way.

Comment: Ok. Even in that case I expect you'll have to `require` it somehow. That's the only way to tell webpack to bundle it.

Comment: I know it is late. But did you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248362/what-is-a-good-way-to-include-a-non-commonjs-library-to-webpack-context?rq=1