# What is a good way to include a non-commonJS library to Webpack context?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, commonjs

I want to include an external and non-commonJS library defining an AngularJS module.

What is a proper way to do it since I obviously **can't** write:

```
import MyLibrary from 'MyLibraryPath'
angular.module('MyApp', MyLibrary)
```

**EDIT---------**

I've just done:

`require('path/myLibrary.js');
angular.module('MyApp', 'moduleName');`

and it works.

Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is fine if the library doesn't export Angular module's [`name` property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#name). Angular wasn't designed with JS modules in mind and originally promotes `angular.module('MyApp', ['moduleName'])` module definition style.

Exporting `name` from the modules is relatively popular convention, especially because the one can do

```
import * as MyLibrary from 'MyLibraryPath';
```

and use it as

```
angular.module('MyApp', [MyLibrary]);
```

If there is no module export, it can be treated with Webpack [exports-loader](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#exporting) and

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            loader: 'exports-loader',
            test: /path\/myLibrary\.js$/,
            query: '"moduleName"'
        }
    ],
},
```

configuration, which essentially adds `module.exports = "moduleName";` to the module.

Use this hack to fix this temporarily if you plan to PR/create an issue for the libraries that don't export `name`. I wouldn't suggest to make the builds more complicated just to keep the code consistent.